# Optimize performance of Removing Hidden Rows in VBA

Tags: performance, vba, loops, excel, filter

I am using the following code to remove hidden/filtered lines after applying autofilters to a big sheet in VBA (big means roughly 30,000 rows):

```
Sub RemoveHiddenRows()
Dim oRow As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRows As Range
With Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set myRows = Intersect(.Range("A:A").EntireRow, .UsedRange)
    If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
End With

For Each oRow In myRows.Columns(1).Cells
    If oRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = oRow
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, oRow)
        End If
    End If
Next
If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

The code comes from here: [Delete Hidden/Invisible Rows after Autofilter Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275423/delete-hidden-invisible-rows-after-autofilter-excel-vba)

Moreover I read this thread: [Speeding Up Code that Removes Hidden Rows on a Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308492/speeding-up-code-that-removes-hidden-rows-on-a-sheet)

The situation: I have applied 5 different filters to a table consisting of 12 columns, therefore a lot of rows are filtered out (hidden) after the process. When I try to delete those, the code above takes a very long time. In my case I don't know if Excel was still working, so I had to force an exit. That leads to the following question:

Is there any other way than looping through all the hidden rows and deleting them?

An idea which came to my mind was to copy only the remaining *unfiltered* (that is non-hidden) content to a new sheet and afterwards delete the old sheet, which contains the full information. If so, how can that be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need to involve another worksheet. Simply copy the rows below the existing [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) and then remove the filter and delete the original data.

```
Sub RemoveHiddenRows()

    With Sheets("Sheet10")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1))) Then
                    .Cells.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
                End If
                .AutoFilter
                .Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

You may also receive some good, focused help on this subject by posting on [Code Review (Excel)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel).

Comment: works 100 x faster than before. And I learned how to use CBool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can improve performance significantly with a function like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub deleteHiddenRows(ByRef ws As Worksheet)

    Dim rngData As Range, rngVisible As Range, rngHidden As Range

    With ws
        Set rngData = .UsedRange
        With rngData
            Set rngVisible = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Set rngHidden = .Columns(1)
        End With
    End With

    If Not (rngVisible Is Nothing) Then

        ws.AutoFilterMode = False

        ' invert hidden / visible
        rngHidden.Rows.Hidden = False
        rngVisible.Rows.Hidden = True

        ' delete hidden and show visible
        rngData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        rngVisible.Rows.Hidden = False

    End If
End Sub
```

I tested it on a file with 2 filters applied to it

The function was adapted from the code in [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24309662/4914662)

Comment: Thanks for your entry. I will test it as well. However I don't think it can be much faster than Jeeped's solution from above, which only takes a couple of seconds to execute even in case of very large files. But maybe it performs equally well :)