# Removing Hidden Rows in VBA - but to maintain formulas in cells

Tags: excel, vba

[Optimize performance of Removing Hidden Rows in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425953/optimize-performance-of-removing-hidden-rows-in-vba)

```
    Sub RemoveHiddenRows()

    With Sheets("Sheet10")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1))) Then
                    .Cells.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
                End If
                .AutoFilter
                .Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I use this method to delete my hidden rows and it worked very fast. However, in my raw data, there are several cells are formulas. The RemoveHiddenRows() will turn my formulas to #DIV/0! which troubles me a lot.

[My Raw Data.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYzpE.png)
*Edit*: The below formulas in the picture are SUM(B:B) and SUM(C:C), sorry for the consusion

For example, if I select "Amy"'s money first, and use the above code to delete others' data, my "sum" and "total" formula will disappear. How can I keep them while using the RemoveHiddenRows(). I really don't have any idea.

Comment: What do formulae `=B:B` and `=C:C` do?

Comment: It’s SUM(B:B) and SUM(C:C)! Sorry for the confusion : (

Comment: That will give you a circular reference error.

Comment: Try  changing the "Total" formulae to `=SUM(INDIRECT("B2:B"&ROW()-1))` and `=SUM(INDIRECT("C2:C"&ROW()-1))`