# Ways to inrease the speed of VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to use VBA for a couple of months now, but I'm not sure I code very efficiently when it comes to speed.

The below code is a calculation of zscores used in a ranking model for stocks. The calculation is quite simple, just a calculation of `zscore=zscore1*weight1+zscore2*weight2....zscoreN*zscoreN`, where the `zscores` are in different sheets and the weights are contained in an array. The code works, but with 500 stocks and 103 periods it takes about 30 seconds to complete. I was looking for advice to speed my code up / make it more "correct" as in terms of good programming practices.

I know my code is a bít messy, but since it works I just hoped I could get some general advice on my way to use loops, if-sentenses and arrays.

```
Public factor() As Single

Sub zscores()
Dim StartTime As Double, EndTime As Double
Dim sheetNames() As String
Dim r As Integer, i As Integer
Dim antalAktier As Integer, perioder As Integer
Dim zscore As Single
StartTime = Timer

Worksheets("ZScores").Range("B2:AAA1000").ClearContents

'perioder and antalAktier is just variables to determine number of stocks and periods
perioder = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("returns").Range("A2:A1500"))
antalAktier = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("returns").Range("B1:AAA1"))

'Makes an array of sheetnames
r = 1
i = 0
ReDim sheetNames(0)
Do Until Worksheets("BloomdataFLDS").Cells(r, 1).Value = ""
    sheetNames(i) = Worksheets("BloomdataFLDS").Cells(r, 1).Value
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve sheetNames(i)
    r = r + 1
Loop

'factor() is an array of values from textboxes in a userform
'Code uses the sheetnames array to jump between sheets and making a weighted average of the cell values and factor array values 
k = 2
For k = 2 To antalAktier + 1
    r = 2
    For r = 2 To perioder + 1
        zscore = 0
        For i = 0 To (UBound(factor) - 18)
            zscore = zscore + (factor(i) * Worksheets(sheetNames(i)).Cells(r, k).Value)
        Next i
        'truncates the value to be max/min +/- 3
        If Worksheets("binær").Cells(k, r).Value = 1 And Worksheets("returns").Cells(r, k).Value <> "#N/A N/A" Then
            If zscore < 3 And zscore > -3 Then
                Worksheets("ZScores").Cells(r, k).Value = zscore
            ElseIf zscore < -3 Then
                Worksheets("ZScores").Cells(r, k).Value = -3
            ElseIf zscore > 3 Then
                Worksheets("ZScores").Cells(r, k).Value = 3
            End If
        Else:
            Worksheets("ZScores").Cells(r, k).Value = ""
        End If
    Next r
Next k
EndTime = Timer
MsgBox "Execution time in seconds: " + Format$(EndTime - StartTime)
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to improve the speed of VBA macro code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016249/how-to-improve-the-speed-of-vba-macro-code)

Answer (score 2):

Generally to speed up your code add

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

to the start of your code &

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

to the end.

I would guess that using VBAs Count function will have at least a slightly better performance than Excel's CountA.
So instead of

```
perioder = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("returns").Range("A2:A1500"))
```

you might be better off using

```
perioder = Worksheets("returns").Range(Range("A2"),Range("A2").end(xlDown)).Count
```

(I am assuming there should be not gaps considering you're Do Loop ends when the cell is empty).

Multiple ReDims is probably slowing you down so I would remove

```
ReDim Preserve sheetNames(i)
```

from your Do Loop & change

```
ReDim sheetNames(0)
```

to

```
ReDim sheetNames(perioder)
```

Also

```
If zscore < 3 And zscore > -3 Then
    Worksheets("ZScores").Cells(r, k).Value = zscore
ElseIf zscore < -3 Then
    Worksheets("ZScores").Cells(r, k).Value = -3
ElseIf zscore > 3 Then
    Worksheets("ZScores").Cells(r, k).Value = 3
End If
```

would be more efficient as

```
With Worksheets("ZScores").Cells(r, k)
   If zscore < 3 And zscore > -3 Then
       .Value = zscore
   ElseIf zscore < -3 Then
       .Value = -3
   ElseIf zscore > 3 Then
       .Value = 3
   End If
End With
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to improve performance is disabling visual feedback. You can just add this in the beginning:

```
Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Excel.Application.Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
Excel.Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And this at the end:

```
Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Excel.Application.Calculation = Excel.xlAutomatic
Excel.Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Also note that `ReDim Preserve sheetNames(i)` takes a lot of time, too. You can use collections instead of an array.

Comment: oh sorry, forgot, I call this from a main sub where I use screenupdating=false and Calculation=manual. But didn't know the EnableEvents thing, thanks..... just put on the EnableEvents thing and it cut about a third of the time! I will look into what Collections are

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much time it will save, but using `ReDim` and `ReDim Preserve` can waste a lot of memory (I'm not sure on how many iterations you make, so this will impact the efficiency of using `ReDim Preserve`).

Each time you perform a `ReDim Preserve`, the array is taken and then copied, creating a new instance of itself with the resized dimensions. You could perform the section of the code without using ReDim Preserve, like below:

```
Dim lrow As Long
Dim sheetNames() As Variant

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
sheetNames = Sheets("BloomdataFLDS").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lrow, 1)).Value
```

Unless there's any reason in particular why you don't wish to have a variant 2d array? When assigning an array from a worksheet, it results in a 2d array, even if you only have 1 dimension worth of data. When you iterate through the array, you just have to specify that the 2nd dimension is always '1'.

As I'm writing this @jbmb2000 has already mentioned the efficiencies for the 2nd loop, so I won't continue. Hope this helps though.

Comment: Thanks Guys, these steps took 2/3rds of the execution time!! I appreciate your help!