# Improve performance with VBA Selection.AutoFill

Tags: vba, excel

I have code like the following:

```
Sub RMS()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Sheets("m1").Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(LEFT(m!R[2]C,FIND(""x"",m!R[2]C & "","")-1))"
    Range("A1:A3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:EZ3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:EZ3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:EZ600"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:EZ600").Select
End Sub
```

This code is running very slow. Is there any help you can give so that code like this could run much faster because I run this code in multiple sheets?

Comment: starts by removing the `Select` and `Selection`, and modify the Ranges directly

Comment: If you search for anything on this topic you will always find a suggestion of turning off screen updating. Why don't you try searching google first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve the speed of VBA macro code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016249/how-to-improve-the-speed-of-vba-macro-code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be faster :

```
Sub RMS()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    With Sheets("m1")
        .Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(LEFT(m!R[2]C,FIND(""x"",m!R[2]C & "","")-1))"
        .Range("A1:A3").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A1:EZ3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        .Range("A1:EZ3").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A1:EZ600"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, for taking time and helping me to find a solution. Its very helpfull